# Фильтр двух столбцов в Google Sheets таблицах

Tags: google-spreadsheet, google-sheets-api

Как осуществлять выборку по двум столбцам A-id и D-дата http://prntscr.com/t4cwkt один раз в день, то есть таких записей может быть 5 (т.е с id = "19252729" и датой '18.06.2020') получать надо только самые первые встречающиеся, остальные отбрасываем и так для всех столбцов A-id и D-дата

Пробовал использовать формулу `=UNIQUE(Data!A2:T)` - но она выбирает только уникальные, то есть например встретились записи http://prntscr.com/t4cwkt то она будет выбирать и делать проверку по всем столбцам, и встретилось несовпадение хоть в одном столбце то уже автоматически будет добавляться

Возможно ли такой запрос реализовать с `=UNIQUE` но проверять только по двум столбцам, чтобы могли добавляться только первые записи с Id и датой не более раза в сутки

Comment: Приведите все данные текстом в вопросе, а не по ссылкам.

Comment: Дубль https://qna.habr.com/q/797789

Answer (score 0):

SORTN с нужным количеством сортировок может решить эту задачу

```
={
  'Лист1'!A1:J1;
  SORTN(SORT('Лист1'!A2:J;1;0;4;0);9^9;2;1;1;4;1)
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Примеры в [Таблице](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FAvGMLejgtlv1ubwsAf_goziM0OCybe7fX9FlAA0pYY/edit?usp=sharing)